# Check with code if an instance is a readable secondary

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

How can I query if an instance is a readable secondary in an AG? E.g. to check if the instance is the primary for an AG then we can use: `select sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica('AGDatabase')`. Is there a similar check for a readable secondary?

Comment: Wouldn't `sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica` return 0 (false) in the cases it's executed against a secondary?

Comment: @J.D.: Yes but it can also return false on a synchronous replica that is not a readable secondary.

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since I worked with AOAGs, but aren't all secondaries read-only and readable (so long as their online)?...is your question really about differentiating between a synchronous and asynchronous secondary?

Comment: ...or are you trying to determine how the secondary is configured for the [`SECONDARY_ROLE` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-only-access-on-an-availability-replica-sql-server) as far as Read Intent vs allowing all connections vs no user connections?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140363/discussion-between-j-d-and-xhr489).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following query returns a row when the given database and current server is not primary and is readable.

```
SELECT ar.secondary_role_allow_connections_desc
FROM   sys.availability_replicas AS ar
       JOIN sys.availability_databases_cluster adc ON adc.group_id = ar.group_id
WHERE  ar.secondary_role_allow_connections > 0
       AND adc.database_name = '<<database>>'
       AND ar.replica_server_name = @@SERVERNAME
       AND sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica('<<database>>') = 0
```